# android weight distribution with multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout

i am creating this layout ... using a shape as a background to make my layout look like a table with several headers

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

 </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
     android:layout_weight="0.2"
     android:adjustViewBounds="true"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
      >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

</LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is when i am testing this code across several devices both in vertical and horizontal landscapes, they are not aligned over each other properly, appears to be each device's width or height affects the weight distribution

and here's the drawable cell border used as a background in each textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"          android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke android:width="0.1dp" android:color="@color/black"
    />
<padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

i don't know really how to solve this, any suggestions ?
[image]

**tablet 7 inch view**

Comment: percentage support library FTW!

Comment: @Mafdy Magdy is this compulsory to use shape??? i have another solution for this using weight in layout.

Comment: @Rumit the idea is to make a table design with columns or borders .... i used the shape in order to do that, it can be done with dividers i believe also but the problem here is the weight and aligning those columns/borders

Comment: hi @ @Mafdy Magdy .... got any solution yet????

Comment: Why do you set android:adjustViewBounds on every View? Don't do that, it might be because you do this the shape (square) interferes with the gravity.

Comment: @TheTool removed them all and still no difference

Comment: @Rumit no solution yet

Comment: You can narrow down the problem by changing the background to a colour instead of the cellborder shape. If the sizes are still weird then we have to fix the gravity, if the sizes are fine after that, we have to fix the cellborder. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below lines

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i tested this and it is working perfectly, should i replace the linear layout with a textview or put the textview inside the layout ? will it make a difference ??

Comment: Thank you feel free to ask help anytime regarding this.. :)

Comment: i was wondering if it is possible to desgin a row style for a listview below this design ... with this same design concept

Answer (score 0):

Android layout:weight property is meant to distribute available space among views horizontally or vertically.

Let's say there four views with weights as A:1,B:2,C:3,D:4.

Then, A will get 1/(1+2+3+4) i.e. 1/10th of space.
B will get 2/(1+2+3+4) i.e. 2/10th of space.
Likewise, C will get 3/(1+2+3+4) i.e. 3/10th of space and D will have 4/10th space.

If you don't want this, then you need to use absolute values like 100dp for width/height.

Hope, this explains the point.
Reflect as appropriate.

Comment: not working ... setting width with absolute value doesn't make it work

Comment: You have to use either. weight or absolute values. If you use absolute value for one of your view, then remaining space will be divided among others. Hope this helps.

Comment: i am not sure if absolute values will make it work on every android device

Answer (score 0):

@Mafdy Magdy, you are doing a little mistack bro., just replace with my code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/cellborder" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and in **cellborder.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="0.1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp" />

</shape>
```

just paste this code.....